# Пропало автозаполнение в WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

До этого писал на react. Решил создать новый js проект. сделал html и js файл. И ни один метод браузерного api webstorm теперь не знает и подчеркивает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать:

**1. Убедитесь, что правильно настроена версия JavaScript:**

- Убедитесь, что в настройках проекта выбрана правильная версия JavaScript. Для этого перейдите в "File" (Файл) -> "Project Structure" (Структура проекта) -> "Project" (Проект) и убедитесь, что версия JavaScript установлена правильно.

**2. Подключите библиотеки:**

- Если вы используете внешние библиотеки, убедитесь, что они подключены к проекту. Вы можете добавить библиотеки, перейдя в "File" (Файл) -> "Project Structure" (Структура проекта) -> "Project" (Проект) -> "Libraries" (Библиотеки) и добавив необходимые библиотеки.

**3. Перезапустите IDE:**

- Иногда перезапуск WebStorm может решить проблему.

**4. Проверьте настройки языка:**

- Проверьте настройки языка для вашего проекта. Для этого перейдите в "File" (Файл) -> "Project Structure" (Структура проекта) -> "Project" (Проект) -> "Project Language Level" (Уровень языка проекта) и убедитесь, что выбран правильный уровень.

**5. Обновите IDE:**

- Убедитесь, что у вас установлена последняя версия WebStorm. Иногда обновления могут внести исправления в работу редактора.

**6. Проверьте настройки автозаполнения:**

- Перейдите в "File" (Файл) -> "Settings" (Настройки) -> "Editor" (Редактор) -> "Code Completion" (Автозавершение кода) и убедитесь, что опции автозаполнения включены и настроены по вашим предпочтениям.

Comment: Обновил - помогло.................................